# Remapping the AltGr key to Control  with setxkbmap

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

Is there a way to remap the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with setxkbmap?

I've already checked the option section in
"/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst" but I didn't find an entry for
<kbd>AltGr</kbd>...

I also tried xmodmap, however some xmodmap entries on my ~/.xsesssionrc
seem to be ignored at system startup,
and they don't take effect. Therefore I decided to achieve that
through setxkbmap or xkb...

My keyboard layout is set to gb (on an italian keyboard).

This is what xmodmap prints:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

And this is what xev prints when I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>:

```
...
state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
...
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestions of the Xorg community I found out the correct setxkbmap command:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:ralt_rctrl
```