# Change Keyboard Layout with both left and right Alt + Shift combos

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use English and Persian keyboard layout on my Ubuntu system. I want to change the keyboard layout both with <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Shift</kbd>. Currently I can not use <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Shift</kbd> to change the Keyboard layout from Persian to English so that I have to use <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Shift</kbd> to change it.

Does anybody know how I can set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to change the keyboard layout on both sides? I use ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks!

Comment: I did the setting to use  `alt+shift` but problem is only `Right Alt+ Right shift` on changing persian to english language

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, yet another try, this one will do the trick I hope... ;)

Credits are due to ***reverendj1***, who described a way of assigning a [Custom key to toggle keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141729/custom-key-to-toggle-keyboard-layout), using **setxkbmap**, which featured in the **workaround** alluded to in **Edit 2** of my previous answer...

> Here is the slightly more involved way, but will give you more
>   flexibility for the key combination. First, copy and paste this script
>   I wrote and name it something like kb_toggle.sh. Make sure to edit
>   LANG1 and LANG2 to be the keyboard layout codes you need.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> LANG1="us"
> LANG2="de"
> CURRENT_LANG=$(setxkbmap -query | tail -n 1 | cut -f6 -d ' ')
> if [ "$CURRENT_LANG" = $LANG1 ]; then
>     setxkbmap $LANG2
> else
>     setxkbmap $LANG1
> fi
> ```
>
> make the file by right-clicking on it -> "Properties" -> "Permissions"
>   tab, then select "Allow executing file as program.
>
> Now, open "System Settings" -> "Keyboard" -> "Shortcuts" tab and
>   select "Custom Shortcuts". Click the + button on the bottom and name
>   the shortcut "Keyboard Toggle" or whatever you want, really. Then give
>   the full path to the script you made earlier in the command box. Hit
>   Apply. Click where it says "Disabled" then you can set the shortcut to
>   whatever you want by clicking your key combination!

I think you'd need to change `"de"` to `"ir"`.

Again, good luck!

---

**Edit**

You may even get away with a [one-liner](http://peppermintos.net/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5194&start=0), if you prefer:

> ```
> setxkbmap us,ir -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
> ```
>
> Now you can switch by pressing alt+shift

See also http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Change_keyboard_layouts and http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.xhtml

---

**Edit 2**

Depending on *how* you decide to achieve your goal, you may want to include `lv3:ralt_alt` in your command, resulting in

```
setxkbmap us,ir -option "lv3:ralt_alt,grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

See `man xkeyboard-config | grep lv3` for  details:

> **lv3:ralt_alt**
>
> Right Alt key never chooses 3rd level
>
> ```
>    xkeyboard-config  provides  the  description files for the X Keyboard Extension (XKB). The configuration options below are
>    usually applied with setxkbmap(1).
> ```

Comment: Thanks. This line works for me: `setxkbmap us,ir -option "lv3:ralt_alt,grp:alt_shift_toggle"`

Comment: What if you want three languages and switch between them circularly but with two directions (right Alt+Shift vs left Alt+Shift

Comment: @ShacharHar-Shuv You could save the above bash script twice, with the two directions hard-coded. Pretty straight-fwd extension of the above, no?

Answer (score 3):

The "right Alt key" is often (always ?) *not* the same as the "left Alt key", but corresponds to the <kbd>**AltGr**</kbd>, see for instance

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_keyboard

and as such has a different-and-distinct function.

You may want to try to try using [**`xdotool`**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261449/how-to-make-caps-lock-change-keyboard-layout-without-delay/262726#262726) to *emulate* certain key combination behaviour. Thus, you could set the

1. `Left` <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `Left` <kbd>Shift</kbd> in the way described by ***Abdulkader*** in his answer, and
2. the second combination as `Right` <kbd>**AltGr**</kbd> + `Right` <kbd>Shift</kbd>) with **`xdotool`**.

---

**Edit**

For a detailed **example** of how this can be done *in general*, **with screenshots**, plz refer to [***izx***'s excellent answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167800/how-to-have-two-sets-of-shortcut-keys-for-compiz-grid-commands-put-left-and-p). Regarding your questions specifically, you *could* try

> **xdotool** key --clearmodifiers **alt+shift**

and then assigning this command to the `Shift+Level3 Shift` (don't type this, just press <kbd>right_Shift</kbd> + <kbd>right_AltGr</kbd>) shortcut in **Custom Shortcuts**. Again, [plz refer to the relevant part of ***izx***'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167800/how-to-have-two-sets-of-shortcut-keys-for-compiz-grid-commands-put-left-and-p).

Voilá, you're sorted.

---

Note that if you tried to do it "the other way around" like so

> xdotool key --clearmodifiers ISO_Level3_Shift+Shift

(or alternatively, but less likely to work, `Alt_R+Shift_R`), noting that [AltGr](http://uk.cqday.com/thread-48610-1-1.html) is "equivalent to" [ISO_Level3_Shift](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1149260.html),

you'd probaly get stuck, because "Alt_R+Shift_R" does ***not*** seem to be offered in the standard layout switching key dialog.

---

**Further reading**: from the [xdotool man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/xdotool.1.html) page:

> Generally, any valid X Keysym string will work. Multiple keys are
>              separated by '+'. Aliases exist for "**alt**", "ctrl", "shift",
>              "super", and "meta" which all map to Foo_L, such as **Alt_L** and
>              Control_L, etc.

also [Remapping the AltGr key to Control  with setxkbmap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107626/remapping-the-altgr-key-to-control-with-setxkbmap?rq=1) may be of interest to you...

---

**Edit 2**

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdotool/+bug/696247 and http://code.google.com/p/semicomplete/issues/detail?id=13 ... and the **workaround** suggested therein (and confirmed to be working as of Nov 2012) of *"The workaround, for now, is to use **setxkbmap** to force your keymap in **xmodmap** (setxkbmap dvorak, etc)"*. Thusly, plz refer to my 2nd, separate answer.

Comment: Thanks. so how can I combine these two keys with `xdotool` ?

Comment: Updated my answer with a how-to.

Comment: I run these code on terminal `xdotool key --clearmodifiers Alt+Shift` AND `xdotool key --clearmodifiers Alt_L+Shift_L` but change only English to persian layout and not `persian to english` I don't know why!

Comment: ok, so when you press `Alt_L+Shift_L` in your current set-up, it toggles between Persion <-> English ?

Comment: ... but pressing `right_Shift + right_AltGr` does *not* toggle, and instead only goes one-way Persian -> English ?

Comment: `right_Shift + right_AltGr` does not toggle, and instead only goes one-way English -> Persian

Comment: `alt_L + shift_L` work correctly and toggle changing

Comment: ok, that's a bit of a bummer; don't know off-hand; will try and find a solution (and/or work-around).

Comment: I opened a new answer outlining a solution using **setxkbmap**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Alt-Shift for both languages

System Settings... → Keyboard Layout → (click on "+" to Add new Language layouts) →

Options... → (click on) "Key(s) to change layout" → (tick) "Left Alt+Left Shift" → Close

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did it but its not working when I want to change layout from persian to english with `right alt`+`right shift`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this command as a [startup application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login):

```
setxkbmap -option lv3:ralt_alt,grp:alt_shift_toggle us,ir
```

This should enable both Alt-Shift toggles. However, you will lose the compositing functionality of the right Alt key (e.g.: you won't be able to draw a Euro sign (€) by hitting RightAlt+E).

`setxkbmap`'s options, including language codes, are documented under `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/base.lst`.

You could test the command out in a terminal first before adding it to your autostart applications.

Source: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=11038 (post #7)

Answer (score 0):

go to keyboard layouts from dash, and then click options, there's an option `key(s) to change layout` check `alt+shift`. This works for me, both alt and shift works even right alt+ left shift works :)

Comment: right `alt+shift` work once. I can't use just right `alt+shift` to change layout. when layout changed to persian, right `alt+shift` not working. you can test it.

Comment: this looks like a bug.or alternatively right alt seems to have some special role in persian keyboard. I'm using `alt+shift` to switch between bengali and english and it works fine

Comment: maybe its not working just for switching from persian language

Comment: yes. doesn't work for persian here. maybe right alt has some other role

Answer (score 0):

Persian and some other layouts are hardcoded to have ISO_Level3_Switch(AltGr or whatever!) instead of Right Alt so when you are in english layout you can use Alt_R + Shift_R/Shift_R + Alt_R to switch to persian but when you are using persian layout the key isn't Alt_R anymore but ISO_Level3_Switch!

Thanks to [**Sneetsher**](https://askubuntu.com/a/471383) we know how to change a hardcoded ISO_Level3_Switch back to normal ALT