# [Left Alt]+Tab doesn't work or How to change a Level3 Shift to a normal ALT?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a problem with my Ubuntu, running 14.04 LTS.

The problem is that I'm trying to user Alt+F4 and Alt+Tab and it doesn't work, it only works with the Right Alt.

I also tried to set a new keyboard short-cut for Alt+F4 and Alt+Tab but as soon as I press Alt the short-cut is set.

The thing I noticed once I set the shortcut is that the key didn't correspond with Alt, it was a Level3 Shift.

I search all over the internet of a method to change that Level3 Shift to the normal Alt but only found solution to do the opposite.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `xev` and `xmodmap`:

1. Run the command `xev` then hover your mouse over the black square.
2. Press the Alt key, and make a note of the following: My output was this (shortened): `KeyPress event... keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), ... XFilterEvent returns: False`
3. The important part is the keycode: Mine was 64, but yours is probably different.
4. Run the command `xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = Alt_L"` substituting `64` for whatever output you get (possibly `135` on your keyboard)
5. This should have changed it. If it has, you then need to run the following command: `xmodmap -pke >~/.Xmodmap`
6. Create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home folder (/home/username)
7. In that file paste the line `xmodmap .Xmodmap`. This should save it forever.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys) answer for details about remapping.

My pronouns are He / Him

Answer (score 6):

Both of these solutions were a bit too hacky for my taste, so I dug a little deeper. The solution I found only uses `dconf-editor`.

Just open `dconf-editor` and search (ctrl+F) for `xkb-options` and update the value. In my case, the value associated with the `xkb-options` key was

```
['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp','lv3:alt_switch']
```

The option `'lv3:alt_switch'` was the one that was causing my headache. I simply changed the value to:

```
['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']
```

That's it!

Answer (score 2):

Check current layout defaults

1. Check used layout/variant names, example my case:

   ```
   $ setxkbmap -query

   rules:      evdev
   model:      pc105
   layout:     us,us
   variant:    altgr-intl
   ```
2. Open the file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` with same name of `layout`.

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
   ```
3. Scroll down to the exact `variant`

   ```
   xkb_symbols "altgr-intl" {

    name[Group1]= "English (international AltGr dead keys)";

   ...

   include "level3(ralt_switch)"
   };
   ```
4. See if you have `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` (or maybe `include "level3(lalt_switch)"`, not sure if that's possible), if so remove its line.
5. Run to update layout

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
   ```

Comment: I have `eek@Eek-PC:~$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
options:    lv3:lalt_switch` and when i modified altgr-intl and removed the include line didn't changed, also, I didn't had any xkb_symbols lv3:lalt_switch. But the other answer helped. Thanks!

Comment: @Eek, Never mind, Your current layout is `us basic` not  `altgr-intl`. However, You have `options: lv3:lalt_switch`, I don't known any thing may come up with this as default, Did you made any customized settings?

Comment: Nope. Default Ubuntu install :-s I have an Asus G74SX maybe from that's where the problem comes :-s